# Export signed package in processing

Tags: android, processing

I've recently been working on an app in processing with the android mode. Everything was going nicely. I created the project itself (and edited the android manifest) but when trying to create the apk file, this error showed up:

Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 in C:\Users\arturo\Documents\Processing\android\sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  >   [Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2].
  >   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  >   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

I tried visiting the sites it recommends me, but I could not fix it. What should I do?

Comment: have you tried, uninstalling and reinstalling Android SDK Build Tools 26.0.2 from the manager? It might ask you to accept the licence. Personally I had to install the SDK from within processing as I could not make it work otherwise. Hope this helps. PEACE.

Comment: Yes, I just had to install againg the android mode and accept the licence. Thanks.